# Is it possible for my discord bot to add another bot to its server?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have two working discord bots and a test server. I want my first bot to add the second bot to the test server. How would I go about this? I have researched it and found nothing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think they can

Comment: @chess_lover_6 I see. I didn't think it had a good chance haha. Thank you for your response!

Comment: No, and thankfully it isn't possible! I can imagine spam bots just adding more and more rogue bots to a server until it becomes unmanageable.

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t possible, bots can’t run other bots cmds or add other bots to a server.